# Netty 4.1 : ioBuffer v.s. directBuffer v.s. heapBuffer

Tags: netty

I am creating ByteBuf to be sent to `Channel` via its `write` or `writeAndFlush` method.

As I understand, direct buffer is better than heap buffer in this case because the latter is managed by JVM and it need be copied to direct buffer on sending out.

Direct buffer is not managed by JVM,  so allocate a lot of direct buffer may cause `OutOfMemoryError`, **correct?**

And I notice there is another method [`ByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer()`](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBufAllocator.html#ioBuffer())
The document says

> Allocate a `ByteBuf`, preferably a direct buffer which is suitable for
>   I/O.

I guess it works in this way:
`ByteBufAllocator` manages two pools, one pool for direct buffer, the other for heap buffer.  If there is insufficient space in direct buffer, then this allocates from heap buffer.  **Am I right?**

How does `ByteBufAllocator` determine the pool size of direct buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Direct buffer is not managed by JVM, so allocate a lot of direct buffer may cause OutOfMemoryError, correct?

Allocating too much of anything without releasing it will cause an OOM.  You'll probably see something like this: 
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory`

> I guess it works in this way:
>   ByteBufAllocator manages two pools, one pool for direct buffer, the other for heap buffer. If there is insufficient space in direct buffer, then this allocates from heap buffer. Am I right?

The truth is even simpler than your guess.  [AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3a4d30df4e3aba7cdc5c8343016e7e13de3ada86/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/AbstractByteBufAllocator.java#L120-L126) will call `directBuffer` for you as long as it can find `sun.misc.Unsafe` on the class path, otherwise it falls back to using `heapBuffer`

```
public ByteBuf ioBuffer() {
    if (PlatformDependent.hasUnsafe()) {
        return directBuffer(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }
    return heapBuffer(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have 16GB physical memory in total, so I should only configure JVM heap to about 8GB(50%) so that the others can be used by direct buffer?